# Kerberos client - kerberoRestTemplate not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kerberos, resttemplate, spring-security-kerberos

Im trying to consume an api which is authenticating with Kerberos. I have referred the below spring documentation related to KerberosRestTemplate.[reference link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/current/reference/html/ssk-resttemplate.html), im passing the correct keytab file and the userPrincipal values as mentioned in the reference doc. But still im receiving 401 from the server.
But when I execute the kinit command in the terminal it receives a ticket from KDC and with that, im able to execute the curl command and get a working response.

```
        KerberosRestTemplate kerberosRestTemplate = new KerberosRestTemplate("svc_dfsd.keytab", "svc_dfsd@sswe.AD");
        String url="https://wexample.com:20550/aggr_subscriber_summary_hbase/03434809824";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_XML));
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = kerberosRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Can you suggest any other better approach to do this or fix this. All your comments are highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting Kerberos might be tricky since the errors are often misleading and Java implementation does a lot if implicit actions (canonicalization of URLs, etc.).

I suggest trying [Kerb4J](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j#spnegokerberos-client) library which allows you to generate the kerberos token explicitly:

```
SpnegoClient spnegoClient = SpnegoClient.loginWithKeyTab("svc_dfsd@sswe.AD", "svc_dfsd.keytab");
SpnegoContext context = spnegoClient.createContext("https://wexample.com"); // Will result in HTTP/wexample.com SPN

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url="https://wexample.com:20550/aggr_subscriber_summary_hbase/03434809824";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_XML));
headers.add("Authorization", context.createTokenAsAuthroizationHeader());
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate .exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

If default SPN resolution works for you, you can also use `SpnegoRestTemplate` from this Kerb4J:

```
SpnegoClient spnegoClient = SpnegoClient.loginWithKeyTab("svc_dfsd@sswe.AD", "svc_dfsd.keytab");

SpnegoRestTemplate spnegoRestTemplate = new SpnegoRestTemplate(spnegoClient);
String url="https://wexample.com:20550/aggr_subscriber_summary_hbase/03434809824";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_XML));
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = spnegoRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Kerb4J